# how to use choice parameter in Jenkins pipeline in batch command

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

how to use choice parameter in Jenkins declarative pipeline in batch command.

I'm using following stage:

```
choice(

        choices: 'apply\ndestroy\n',
        description: '',
        name: 'DESTROY_OR_APPLY')

     stage ('temp') {

        steps {

            echo "type ${params.DESTROY_OR_APPLY}"
            bat'echo "type01 ${params.DESTROY_OR_APPLY}"'
            bat'echo "type01 %{params.DESTROY_OR_APPLY}%"'
            bat'echo  type01 [${params.DESTROY_OR_APPLY}]'
```

}

echo does resolve to correct parameter value but under bat none of the above code works.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got the syntax right.
If you change it to one of the below options, the bat command receives the value of your choice.

```
steps {
      bat "echo type01 ${DESTROY_OR_APPLY}"
}
```

or

```
steps {
      bat 'echo type01 ' + DESTROY_OR_APPLY
}
```

You can also use `${params.DESTROY_OR_APPLY}` in the first or `params.DESTROY_OR_APPLY` in the second example if you want to use the params definition consequently in your code.